# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NextJS and Prisma

Tags: sql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I am getting the following error from my API.

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Here's an example of the code.

```
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'

export default async(req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.id
    console.log(id)

    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        const data = await prisma.intranet_employees.findMany({
            where: {
                OR: [
                    {
                        First_Name: {
                            contains: String(id),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        Last_Name: {
                            contains: String(id),
                        },
                    }
                ],                
            },
        })
        res.json({ data: data })
        
    }
    if(req.method == 'PUT'){
        const body = req.body
        const data = await prisma.intranet_employees.update({
            where: {
                employee_id: Number(id)
            },
            data: {
                Last_Name: body.Last_Name,
                First_Name: body.First_Name,
            }
        })
        res.json({ message: data })
        
    }
    if(req.method == 'DELETE'){
        const data = await prisma.intranet_employees.update({
            where: {
                employee_id: Number(id)
            },
            data: {
                active_flag: 0
            }
        })
        res.json({ message: data })
        
    }
    else{
        return res.json({ message: 'Method not allowed.' })
    }
}
```

Here is the component in which the API is being called to get data:

```
async function onChange(e){
      const name = e.target.value
      console.log(name)
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/employees/${name}`)
      
      setData(res.data.data)
      console.log(data)
  }

  const SearchForm = () => {
      return (
          <FormControl id="employeeSearchForm">
              <Input 
                  id="empSearch"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search Employees" 
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
          </FormControl>
      )
  }
```

It looks like this is coming from the res.json obviously.  Not sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: How are you calling the `async` function?, you will need to post the surrounding code that consumes this data. The error usually means you have already sent some other response to the client, so this is acting as a duplicate sender.

Comment: Hi Ramakay, I updated it to include the entire API route

Comment: You will still need to add the consumer, wherever async is being called - which route or function calls or consumes this API?

Comment: Added the component

Comment: What does ` setData(res.data.data)` do?

Comment: It's a useState() function in react. just the setter function

Comment: if request.method equals GET, res.json will be executed, after that, it will execute res.json located on else code block. The res.json sentence does not finish the code execution, you have to add a return before the res.json sentence located on GET code block and PUT code block

Comment: That was the issue, easy fix.  Thank you!